# Selenium Not Finding Element Present in HTML Even After Waiting for DOM to update

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape information on a website where the information is not immediately present. When you click a certain button, the page begins to load new content on the bottom of the page, and after it's done loading, red text shows up as "Assists (At Least)". I am able to find the first button "Go to Prop builder", which doesn't immediately show up on the page, but after the script clicks the button, it times out when trying to find the "Assists (At Least)" text, in spite of the script sleeping and being present on the screen.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bovada.lv/sports/basketball/nba')

# this part succeeds
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Go to Prop builder']")
    )
)
element.click()
time.sleep(5)

# this part fails 
element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Assists (At Least)']")
    )
)
time.sleep(2)

innerHTML = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
driver.quit()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the Assist element is under a frame. You need to switch to the frame like this:

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"player-props-frame")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout to confirm the timeout provided is correct, You can also confirm using debug mode. If still issue persist, please check "Assists (At Least)" element do not fall under any frame.

You can also share the DOM and proper error message if issue not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions you could try,

- Make sure that the content loaded at the bottom of the is not in a frame. If it is, you need to switch to the particular frame
- Check the XPath is correct, try the XPath is matching from the Developer Console
  [image: XPath Check]

Inspect the element from the browser, once the Developer console is open, press CTRL +F and then try your XPath. if it's not highlighting check frames

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is are any iframes in the page, search for iframe in the view page source, and if you find any for that field which you are looking for, then switch to that frame first.
   driver.switch_to.frame("name of the iframe")
2. Try adding a re-try logic with timeout, and a refresh button if any on the page
   st = time.time()
   while st+180>time.time():
   try:
   element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
   EC.visibility_of_element_located(
   (By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Assists (At Least)']")
   )
   )
   except:
   pass

Answer (score 0):

The content you want is in an iFrame. You can access it by switching to it first, like this:

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[class="player-props-frame"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Answer (score -1):

Round brackets are the issue here (at least in some cases...). If possible, use .contains selector:
`//*[contains(text(),'Assists ') and contains(text(),'At Least')]`

Comment: I tried that but still got a timeout exception. There's another similar element that shows up with text "FAQ" that doesn't have round brackets, and I tried searching by that instead of "Assists (At Least)", but also got a timeout exception